# Sendmail: DSN: Service unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, php, email, sendmail, apache-2.4

I've been having trouble getting my server to send email and I haven't for the life of me figured out how to fix it. If anyone could give me some simple pointers, that would be muchly appreciated!

```
May 19 15:36:03 ubuntu-12 sm-mta[2484]: s4JFa3jp002484: from=<www-data@ubuntu-12.04-     production>, size=412, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201405191535.s4JFZw4c002483@ubuntu-12.04-  production>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=ip6-localhost [127.0.0.1]
May 19 15:36:03 ubuntu-12 sendmail[2483]: s4JFZw4c002483: to=myname@mycompany.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:05, xdelay=00:00:05, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s4JFa3jp002484 Message accepted for delivery)
May 19 15:36:03 ubuntu-12 sm-mta[2487]: s4JFa3jp002484: to=<myname@mycompany.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ubuntu-12.04-production> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120412, relay=mailserver.mycompany.com. [213.171.216.115], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavaila$
May 19 15:36:03 ubuntu-12 sm-mta[2487]: s4JFa3jp002484: s4JFa3jp002487: DSN: Service unavailable
May 19 15:36:03 ubuntu-12 sm-mta[2487]: s4JFa3jp002487: to=<www-data@ubuntu-12.04-production>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the line? It is cut off at the right.

Comment: 'Service unavailable' - That's all that's left of that line

Answer (score 1):

The third line of that output tells me that the sending server is working fine, but the receving server, "mailserver.mycompany.com", is not listening for incoming mail. Either the service is turned off or it is not listening to the external address.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to mail, but the address it's trying to send to is fine and receives email daily. I can't help think it's something wrong with the sendmail config. Thanks for your help!