# unable to send email with php: Message accepted but never received

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

Here is the complete mail.log

```
Jul 14 16:48:20 rezocoquin sendmail[5861]: v6EEmKCT005861: from=www-data, size=194, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201707141448.v6EEmKCT005861@rezocoquin.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Jul 14 16:48:20 rezocoquin sm-mta[5863]: v6EEmKvf005863: from=<www-data@rezocoquin.com>, size=419, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201707141448.v6EEmKCT005861@rezocoquin.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=rezocoquin.com [127.0.0.1]
Jul 14 16:48:20 rezocoquin sendmail[5861]: v6EEmKCT005861: to=yarekc@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30194, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v6EEmKvf005863 Message accepted$
Jul 14 16:48:20 rezocoquin sm-mta[5868]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Jul 14 16:48:20 rezocoquin sm-mta[5868]: v6EEmKvf005863: to=<yarekc@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@rezocoquin.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120419, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [IPv6:2a00:1450:400c:c07::1b], d$
Jul 14 16:48:20 rezocoquin sm-mta[5868]: v6EEmKvf005863: v6EEmKvf005868: DSN: Service unavailable
Jul 14 16:48:21 rezocoquin sm-mta[5868]: v6EEmKvf005868: to=<www-data@rezocoquin.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

-> No email is received: any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The message was accepted by your own mail relay server; Google's server rejected the message from your relay server. See here for more information about the problem you're encountering: [Sendmail: DSN: Service unavailable](https://serverfault.com/questions/597008/sendmail-dsn-service-unavailable)

You can see your mail relay is using IPv6 to deliver the message. Perhaps your DNS server is configured to return IPv6 addresses but the target server is not reachable by IPv6 from your server.